# How to get last message id from Telegram Channel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I need to get last message ID from Telegram Channel in `channel_message_id`, here is my Code:

```
import telegram

bot = telegram.Bot(token='TOKEN')

user_id = 745466988

updates = bot.get_updates()

channel_message_id = 100

channel_id = '@Space_of_Cars'

bot.forward_message(chat_id=user_id, from_chat_id=channel_id, message_id=channel_message_id)
```

Have someone any ideas?

I tried to ask ChatGPT, but he didn't give me correct answer.

Comment: Please give us a (better) description of the problems/errors you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Only functionality listed in the [Bot API docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) is available to be used by telegram bots. If you want to know the last message id, you'll have to keep track of it.